# Pandas pivoting for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like - `df = pd.DataFrame([['10/03/2020', 'H1', 'x', 2.5], ['10/03/2020', 'H2', 'x', 3.5], ['10/03/2020', 'H1', 'y', 2], ['10/03/2020', 'H2', 'y', 3]], columns=['Day', 'Hour', 'Var', 'Val'])`

```
          Day Hour Var  Val
0  10/03/2020   H1   x  2.5
1  10/03/2020   H2   x  3.5
2  10/03/2020   H1   y  2.0
3  10/03/2020   H2   y  3.0
```

I want the result to be - `pd.DataFrame([['10/03/2020', 'x', 2.5, 3.5], ['10/03/2020', 'y', 2, 3]], columns=['Day', 'Var', 'H1', 'H2'])`

```
          Day Var   H1   H2
0  10/03/2020   x  2.5  3.5
1  10/03/2020   y  2.0  3.0
```

What is the best way to do this in pandas?
Sorry if this is a repeat question. If so, feel free to just point me to the earlier answered question

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pivot` method to do the bulk of the work, and then use `reset_index` to move "Day" from the index into its own column. I use `rename_axis` because I don't like my column Index having a name and think it messes with new users:

```
pivotted_df = (
    df.pivot(index=["Day", "Var"], columns="Hour", values="Val")
    .rename_axis(columns=None)   # Remove the name of the column index. Visual purposes only 
    .reset_index()               # Insert "day" as a column instead of it being the index
)

print(pivotted_df)
          Day Var   H1   H2
0  10/03/2020   x  2.5  3.5
1  10/03/2020   y  2.0  3.0
```

I would encourage you to try commenting out each of the `rename_axis(...)` and the `reset_index()` lines to see what each step of this process and visualize what they're each doing!

Comment: `pivotted_df = (df.pivot(index=["Day", "Var"], columns="Hour", values="Val"))` When I use this piece of code, it gives me an error - `ValueError: Length of passed values is 4, index implies 2`. I don't know if this a version issue or something.

Comment: Yeah, I believe to pass index as more than 1 level you need pandas version > 1. You can check your version with `import pandas as pd; print(pd.__version__)` If you can't upgrade you can try `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`, but you'll need to check your output to ensure that none of your values were aggregated in the process.